# как вернуть массив из функции в react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const countTax = (value, e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      let max = 260000;
      let yearTax = (value * 12) * 0.13;
      let wholeNumber = parseInt(max / yearTax);
      let remainder = max - yearTax * wholeNumber;
      let arr = Array(wholeNumber).fill(yearTax);
      if (remainder !== 0) {
         arr.push(remainder);
         return arr;
      }
   }
```

Эта функция принимает в себя то что ввел в инпут пользователь, как мне вернуть из нее массив?

Comment: Эта функция возвращает массив. В чём проблема-то?

Comment: ```<button className="popup-form__btn" onClick={(e) => countTax(inputRef.current.value, e)}>Рассчитать</button> ```  эта функция вызывается здесь, в нее заходят данные, и мне из этой функции нужно достать массив чтобы его элементы ракидать по html

Comment: Напиши название функции например onClick='getMas()' вынеси её ( getMas() ) в js файл, или тэг скрипт, что там у тебя.. И присваивай значение возвращаемое из функции какой-то переменной, или же передай аргументом в функцию которая будет раскидывать..

Comment: А куда по вашему должна возвращать отает функция которая вызывается как обработчик события? Попробуйте почитать дня начала учебник по реакту

Comment: ```const getData = (value, e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      countTax(value);

   } ```

Comment: Все получилось, использовал useState